# Complex algorithmic analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

So, in my data structures class we recently learned about algorithmic analysis and Big-O analysis. We really only applied it to sorting algorithms so far, which are relatively simple to analyze. I was curious about how to analyze more complex algorithms.

For example, I wrote this python algorithm for a program I'm working on to read all bytes in from a file and divide them into blocks using 4 byte tags that separate the data. Each tag starts with an 'h' and I have a separate list of the possible tags that I use when determining if a 4 byte sequence is a tag. The algorithm is defined below

```
data = file.read()
blocks = []
tagIndexes = []
i = data.index(b'h')
try:
    while 1:
        if data[i:i+4] in tags:
            tagIndexes += [i]
        i = data.index(b'h', i+1)
except ValueError:
    pass
for j in range(len(tagIndexes) - 1):
    index = tagIndexes[j]
    nextIndex = tagIndexes[j+1]
    blocks += [block(data[index:index+4], data[index+4:nextIndex])]
lastIndex = tagIndexes[len(tagIndexes) - 1]
blocks += [block(data[lastIndex:lastIndex+4], data[lastIndex+4:])]
return blocks
```

I'm not asking about comments on how I might improve the algorithm. I'll be able to do that myself if necessary later. My question is how might I determine the worst case scenario or the Big-O notation for this algorithm. There are several sub-algorithms within it, and it's quite easy to see the worst case for most of the smaller ones. For example, the worst case of python's list.index(val) method would be if there were none of the specified values in the list, in which case it would just loop through the whole thing and raise an error O(n). However, the worst case of the loop around that method would be if every byte was an 'h' O(n). But in that case each call to data.index() would be very fast and immediately return a value O(1). And then the worst case for the second loop would be if every 4 bytes was a tag O(n/4).

How do I analyze this for the worst possible case encompassing the whole algorithm, not just the parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most important tips for this analysis are:

1. Remember that only the most dominant summand matters and that constant factors can be ignored.
2. Analyze the loops from the inside out.

So the steps are:

- The first 4 lines are all in `O(n)`.
- The inside of the while loop is in `O(1+k) = O(k)`:

  - `in tags` is in `O(t)` with `t` being the number of known tags. As that number is not related to `n`, this is the same as `O(1)`.
  - `tagIndexes += [i]` is in `O(1)` [[source]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)
  - `data.index()` is in `O(k)`, with `k` being the average distance of tags in the input data
- The number of loop iterations is `n/k`. Now you mulitply the number of iterations with the cost of one iteration and you have `O(n)` for the first loop.
- The inside of the for loop is in `O(k)` (assuming `block(a,b)` is `O(len(a)+len(b))`):

  - The first two index accesses are `O(1)`
  - `data[index+4:nextIndex]` is `O(k-4) = O(k)`. `block(...)` is also `O(k)`. Thats actually 2 `k`, but as we can ignore constant factors, this whole line is `O(k)`.
- The loop once again runs `n/k` times, so it’s also in `O(n)`.

So the total time of the algorithm is `O(n)` as once again constant factors and all smaller summands are are ignored.

Hope that helps – leave a comment if you have any questions.

Apart from that, here are two small style-related pointers for your code:

- It’s `while True`, not `while 1`.
- You access the last element of a list via `list[-1]`, not `list[len(list)-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

What you already realized is that while finding worst case scenarios for each part of the algorithm is relatively easy, they sometimes are somewhat incompatible, i.e. they can't occur together. But worst case analysis doesn't care about that; its purpose is to give you an upper bound on the running time/space usage, so it is alright if the bound you end up with is so bad that it will never actually happen. We always are interested in as tight a bound as possible, but sometimes there is no really tight bound that can be proven by a straightforward approach; in those cases, the analysis tends to end up worse than the algorithm actually performs, and that's why worst case analysis is often times called a "pessimistic" approach.

To deal with this problem of worst case bounds not being as tight as we would like them to be, there are a couple approaches you can try: there's amortized analysis, which deals with the cost of sequences of operations, which sometimes gives tighter bounds than just looking at a single operation; there's probabilistic analysis, which uses probabilities to see whether the frequency with which the expensive stuff needs to be done can help to bring down the expected running time/space usage; and there's average case analysis, which is basically probabilistic analysis where you assume that all possible inputs have the same probability. Those three methods have varying difficulty depending on the algorithm at hand and tend to be used for more advanced algorithms and data structures, because those often times don't lend themselves to the straightforward worst case approach.

So to sum up: worst case analysis isn't always going to give you tight bounds, that's why it's sometimes called pessimistic. There are other analysis techniques you can use to try and get tighter bounds, but even those won't always help. Given that you just started out with algorithms and their analysis, I very much doubt you have heard of those techniques before, let alone applied them, so going with your worst case analysis is perfectly fine, don't worry about the result not being a tight bound.